# How to Set https certificate failure then automatically Redirect another Site in IIS

Tags: windows, iis, web-hosting

My Site have ssl certificate but its expired how to i set redirect another URL.

Comment: Can you state the question more clearly? It is not clear at all what you want to do and where.

Comment: Configuring redirection in IIS is not a security question, but an IIS question. Migrating.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect away from https if you have a bad (i.e. expired in your case) certificate. To get the redirect instruction the client has to first connect to the site and do a successful SSL/TLS handshake. Only after this is done the client will receive the response which redirects it away. Since a successful handshake will not happen due to the bad certificate the client will not get to the redirect.

Your only choice is to get a valid certificate for the site and install it. Once you've done it you will be able to redirect the clients away from the https site.